# Material doesn't apply properly to the mesh Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I created a mesh (parallelogram) in code in Unity and i have a prefab of this object with mesh renderer, I tried to apply material [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPbWu.png) to this renderer [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eca8n.png) and it is applying one color from the texture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy1Dy.png) (maybe a small part of it for some reason). Here are pictures. Thanks for answers

Comment: The issue is almost certainly [a UV problem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv.html). The mesh vertices set the location of the mesh in space and the UV coordinates determine how a texture maps to the mesh.

Comment: ayy happy to help :)